# How to see output on VS Code with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am doing some code challenges using Typescript in VS code. When I try to run the code and see the output, I get "Code Language is not supported or defined". The language mode is set to Typescript React (I also tried just Typescript). And the file has a .tsx ending. Finally, I also did compile the file and make a duplicate .js version. Is there something I am forgetting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run a typescript file the way you would run a javascript file. You will need to first compile your typescript file into javascript with the command below in the directory containing your `.ts` file:

```
npx tsc -w <your-file-name.ts>
```

The command above will create a `<your-file-name.js>` file in the same directory and keep watching for any realtime changes with `-w` option. Then you can run the `.js` file in the same directory with either node or [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) like this:

```
node <your-file-name.js>
```

---UPDATE---

Having to input these two commands mentioned above `tsc -w` and `node <your-file-name.js>` every time you might get cumbersome after a few times, you can use the [`ts-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) command which combines both of the commands stated above into one:

```
ts-node <your-file-name.ts>
```

Comment: There's a packaged called [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) which will let you run TypeScript files without precompiling.

Comment: That's correct, thank you for sharing this, I will update my response now.

Answer (score 0):

Run npx tsc -w
And in another terminal run node filename.js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the fact that your file ends with .tsx you are probably using React. I will also assume that you used create-react-app to init your project.

If both of my assumptions are correct, try:

```
npm start
```

If you are new to both React and Typescript, I would also suggest taking a look into that tool as it creates a very decent starting point for you to start learning both. https://create-react-app.dev/